# Black borders around windows / black terminal

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, intel

I am under 16.04 on Asus Zenbook UX305C and my system was a bit laggy graphically. I decided to try to install other drivers/proprietary intel drivers, but after that, I got black borders around windows/black terminal. Symptoms are similar to other posts, but anything i've tried from other posts did not solve my issue.

I'm thus a bit stuck :-)

```
  *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
   resources: irq:125 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:191e] (rev 07)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics [1043:1cfd]
Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
Kernel modules: i915_bpo
```

I added some logs that are usually asked in other posts. If someone has a lead, i'd be glad.